# I need to show that the intersection of $T$ and $ \bar{I}$ is equal to empty as well.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology

Lets assume that $T⊂R^{n}$ is open and $I⊂R^n$ & $T\cap I=\varnothing$.

I need to show that the intersection of $T$ and $\bar{I}$ (the closure of $I$) is empty as well.

How to show this? I have seen this question in a book.but I have No idea. I wonder the solution. Help me. Thank you!

Comment: What you're asking to prove is untrue. Are you sure you're asking the right question? Could it be to prove $T^c\cap I^c=\emptyset$?

Comment: I changed $T\cap I=empty$ to $T\cap I=\varnothing$.  One could write instead $T\cap I=\emptyset$ or $T\cap I=\mathrm{empty}$ (here I used \mathrm{empty}), but I think the way it was could be considered wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  Since $T$ is open, the complement of $T$ is closed.  So now what happens when you take the closure of $I$?  How could it possibly have non-empty intersection with $T$?

(Note that $I$ is contained in the complement of $T$, since $I\cap T = \emptyset$.)

Comment: Sorry:( I cannot understand:/ I am confused. Please can you sole explicitly?

Comment: please explain more expicit.:/

Comment: Sorry, no time just now.  I'm going to sleep.  Let me know if you still haven't managed to figure it out in 13 hours or so (I really did provide quite a bit of direction).

Comment: Ok thank you. Have a good dream!

Comment: @B11 You have everything you need in this answer. Since $T\cap I=\emptyset$, we have $I\subseteq T^c=\mathbb{R}^n\setminus T$ (this is actually equivalent). Now $T^c$ is closed as the complement of an open set. So taking the closure on both sides of the latter inclusion, we get $\overline{I}\subseteq T^c$. This means $T\cap \overline{I}=\emptyset$. So what you really need to understand here is that $A\cap B=\emptyset$ if and only if $A\subseteq B^c$.

Comment: @julien thank you. The question is clear. However this is explained by so many question marker. So I am confused a bit.

Comment: @B11:  I asked questions in my answer because I wanted to encourage you to think some things through yourself.  Can you answer the questions in my answer?

Comment: @B11:  Oh, about "Have a good dream": just before I woke up I dreamt that this question had actually been about ideals in rings and not about topology, and there were a huge number of comments about how stupid I was for posting such an off-the-mark answer!

Comment: @TaraB I though your questions in answer. And again and again I read some thm's related to this subject. And then I understood. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @B11:  No problem!  Maybe you could write up a full answer to the question and accept it, to show this is finished with?